# How will the Win10 free upgrade work?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a laptop with Win7 that I would like to upgrade to Win10, but if I install Win7 and then upgrade to Win10 through the Windows Update manager (When available), is my license key then added as a valid Win 10 key and can I then just make a clean install afterwards?

Comment: I dont' think that there is a definitive answer yet. Windows 10 has not reached RTM, so everybody can only guess. 
What I have read/heard/whatever is that Windows 7 and 8.1 users get a Windows 10 license for 1 year after release. It is guessed (!) that this license will be valid for the lifetime of the device.
I'd also be interested in how they handle this, but we'll know when it gets released.

Comment: If it works like anything like the Media Center upgrade, all you will do is purchase it at a cost of $0.00, and you will be sent a license key that can be used to download an .ISO or use the tool itself to upgrade to WIndows 10.  You might have to wait awhile for an answer.  This has the potential to be a great question, so any answers should be great, which means they should provide resources to backup your answer.

Comment: Supposedly it'll be via Windows Update for 7SP1 and the most recent W8.1, others will have to download an ISO.

Comment: For now it will be [via windows update](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/how-windows-10-upgrades-might-work) as suggested by user3710044. [Also see this](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2898794/heres-how-windows-10-upgrade-paths-will-work.html)